# Why is this not rendering the map on the screen? I'm the using the D3 library and my geojson file is working fine

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

```
<script>
const width  = 960;
const height = 500;

const svg = d3.select('svg')
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

const projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], 'resources/lebanese-map.geojson');

const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

svg.append('svg')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data('resources/lebanese-map.geojson'.features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .style("fill", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("stroke", "black");
</script>
```

It's just not displaying anything.
I'm using WebStorm and the newest version of d3 that's why you can see the fitSize function added in v4 I guess.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your data appears to be a string: `'resources/lebanese-map.geojson'` - this is not geojson and does not have a features property, you need to load your file with `d3.json('resources/lebanese-map.geojson').then(function(geojson) { /* do something with geojson here */ })`

Comment: I tried to but still it did not work.  @AndrewReid

Comment: You also need to set the projection fitSize in the .then() function - as it uses the geojson as well. *Possibly applicable: also, you'll need to run the script on a server, otherwise d3.json cannot access the geojson due to browser restrictions.*

Comment: Thank you @AndrewReid Worked perfectly